# How to plot over plot using two dataframe data and for loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two df like following:

```
df1:
date, ticker, y_true
1/1, A, 10
1/2, A, 8
...
1/1, B, 10
1/2, B, 8
...

df2:
date, ticker, y_predict, y_predict_upper, y_predict_lower
8/1, A, 10,13,8
8/2, A, 8,9,1
...
8/1, B, 10,13,8
8/2, B, 8,9,1
...
```

**So I want to plot each ticker, making them subplots. I also want to plot df1 and df2 in one subplot, group by ticker value. Dates in df2 is a set of in-sample dates of df1. So I am wondering how to plot over a plot.**

I already have the code to plot df1:

```
ticker_list = ['A','B','C',...]
# define subplot grid
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=8, ncols=1, figsize=(15, 60),dpi=150)


# loop through tickers and axes
for ticker, ax in zip(ticker_list, axs.ravel()):
    # filter df for ticker and plot on specified axes
    df1[df1["ticker"] == ticker].plot(ax=ax)

    ##for_loop_forecast[for_loop_forecast["ticker"] == ticker].plot(ax=ax)

    # chart formatting
    ax.set_title(ticker.upper())
    ax.get_legend().remove()
    ax.set_xlabel("")
    

plt.show()
```

Comment: Kindly check gridSpec and grdiSpecSubplots https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html

Comment: Simply add a code specifying another data frame. `df2[df2["ticker"] == ticker].plot(ax=ax)`